# SWI-Prolog C++ interface

Tags: c++, windows, prolog, swi-prolog

I get an error while trying to load a DLL generated with swipl-ld in prolog
the predicate that throws the exception is this

```
initialization(shlib:use_foreign_library('C:/Users/valquiria.duarte/Desktop/dlog-server-0.3-beta-source/dlog-server/output/hash_swi.dll', install)),
```

and the exception is this one

```
ERROR: '$open_shared_object'/3: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: I looked at SWI-Prolog's current documentation for the **use_foreign_library/2** predicate, and I don't see `install` listed there as an option for the second argument.  My reading is that atom `now` is the only meaningful option.  Have you tried removing that second argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this note at ComputerHope](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000726.htm), Windows may report this error when the file is missing (or corrupt).  It appears the filepath is fully specified in the the call to **use_foreign_library**, but it's worth double-checking that the path is correct about where the DLL is located.

It seems a little odd that you reported the parametric form of the ERROR message, where %1 is a placeholder for the actual filename.  If that was how the error appeared on your computer, it suggests there is some failure to parse the exception details as they were thrown up the handler-chain.

If the message *does* contain the actual path and filename, then you should confirm their accuracy and the file's existence on the given path.  It seems you have correctly called **use-foreign_library** using SWI-Prolog's preferred syntax of forward slashes in the filepath to separate directories.  However it is the Window's operating system (more specifically the system-dependent implementation of `dlopen()`) that generates the error, and the resulting error message I would expect to contain a filepath and filename that contain backslashes.